# Using ajax with laravel 5.2

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I want to display a table using ajax when something is typed in the search box. 
Before generating any table I am just testing that the ajax call is reached to the controller or not by printing the searched keyword. But it is not working. I think the problem is in the url. But I don't know what could be the solution.

Here is my view:

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searched_key"    id="searched_key">

 <div id="live-data"></div>
```

Here is my ajax:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searched_key").keyup(function () {
        var string = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "form_value",
          data: {searched_key: $string},
          success: function (data) {
              $("#live-data").html(data);
          }
      });

  });

});
```

Here is my controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
 public function get_applicants_info(){

     $key_word = $_POST['searched_key'];

     echo $key_word;  //to test the ajax call
}
}
```

Here is my routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::post('form','HomeController@store');

Route::post('form_value','HomeController@get_applicants_info');
```

Comment: I take it nothing is happening on the page? Go to developer tools -> network and click on the XHR tab. See what response is being sent back.

Comment: check networks tab

Comment: ^ check your networks tab and see what request is actually being sent and where it is going.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is with your AJAX url. Instead of specifying the URL directly try using url() function (In case you are using blade engine).

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searched_key").keyup(function () {
        var string = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "{{url(form_value)}}", <= change your url to this.
          data: {searched_key: $string},
          success: function (data) {
              $("#live-data").html(data);
          }
      });

  });

});
```